# How to request data from Database by passing an ID with JQuery, generate new Jquery code and execute it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I try to create a "Point Of Sale" script with PHP, JQuery, MySQL.

I have 3 files; "NewOrder.php", "PullDataFromDb.php", "CustomScript.js" ...

At NewOrder.php, there is a select box with `id="SlctCat"` and options `< option value="1">Category 1< /option>`, and 2, 3 and so on..

My New Order page code is like this;

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="CategorySelect">
    <label class="control-label">Select Category</label>
                <select data-placeholder="Please Select a Category" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2" id="SlctCat" name="SlctCat" onchange="aracCekiyor(this.value);">
              <option value=""></option>
              <?php  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories",$baglan);
              while ($m = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {echo '<option value="'.$m["id"].'">'.$m["name"].'</option>'; }
              ?>
          </select>
  </div>
 
<div class="col-md-8" id="productsForm">
  <div id="CategoryResults">
    results will be here
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS code is like this;

```
function aracCekiyor(str) {
    document.getElementById("CategorySelect").innerHTML=" Selected (this is because I don't want to load another category's products still page have another category's products)"; 
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("CategoryResults").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("CategoryResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","include/PullDataFromDb.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And last file PullDataFromDb.php code is this;

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$productsToPage = '';
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorystandartproducts WHERE carID LIKE $q ORDER BY id ASC",$baglan); 
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $urID = $row['productID'];
$i++;
        $mal= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id LIKE $urID",$baglan); 
        while($z = mysql_fetch_array($mal)) {
            $productsToPage .= '
            <div class="row" id="CatProductRow'.$i.'">
            <div class="col-md-6">'.$z['name'].'</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">'.$z['price'].'</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">'.$z['tax'].'</div>
            <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="CatProdRowRemove'.$i.'"> x</a></div>
            <script>
            $( "#CatProdRowRemove'.$i.'" ).click(function()     {
            $( "#CatProductRow'.$i.'" ).remove();
                                                        });
            </script>
</div>
            
            ';
        }
}

echo $productsToPage;
```

**Scenario is;**

- **Open New Order page**
- **Select a category**
- **When "Select" changed, page triggers the JS and post selected Category ID to PullDataFromDB page**
- **Page returns with response**
- **Response data goes where it needs to be**

Every product rows come with a price and a remove button. In my page a have a Grand Total Input. I need to Sum all the product's prices which exist on page.

I add some extra JS code to PullDataFromDB page to give life those remove buttons, but they did not work.

### So, in short,

- **I need to pull every product which selected by customer**
- **I need to sum all the prices**
- **If i need to remove some of the product, i would be remove them and off course the price would be change.**

Comment: 'mysql_' functions should no longer be used [look here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). You should switch to mysqli.

Comment: I know bro, but this is not the case... thanks